# Wordpress Website is not displaying any background color

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, background-color

While updating a post for one of my client's websites www.professionalaccess.com it seems the background black color has disappeared. I am unable to diagnose the error as all my stylesheet says the color as #000.

Can you help me figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `body`, `.wrapper`, `.content` and `.header_bottom` all has `background-color: #fff`. That makes the color of the background, white.

Comment: Thanks could you point me which file exactly because all my css files in wordpress are showing #000

Comment: It is the stylesheet.min.css that makes it white.

Comment: The wordpress editor doesnot show the option to edit the stylesheet.min.css any other way to edit this?

Comment: Try adding `.content, .header_bottom { backgorund:#000 !important;}` to a css-file you can edit, and make sure that the file is loaded by the site.

Comment: I changed these in style.css although can't see any change whatsoever. I just noticed my Chrome devtools is giving the error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://www.professionalaccess.com/wp-content/themes/codewave/css/style_dynamic.php?ver=3.9.2

Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: It might be. It seems like it doesn't even load the styles.css where you have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the white (#fff) in your `style.css`
If it still doesn't work try this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/color-scheme-every-theme/